# How to get xml response from URL in Java and store It in MONGODB

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to request one URL which will return a xml response like following:

```
<SERVERPERFORMANCEMETRICS>
<SERVERNAME>abc</SERVERNAME> 
<SERVERSTARTUPTIME>11/25/2016 11:00 AM</SERVERSTARTUPTIME> 
<TOTALMASTERREQUESTS>4</TOTALMASTERREQUESTS> 
<TOTALRENDERERREQUESTS>13</TOTALRENDERERREQUESTS> 
<FAILEDREQUESTS>10</FAILEDREQUESTS>
</SERVERPERFORMANCEMETRICS>
```

and now I want to parse and store this xml's data in MONGODB.

```
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; 


        MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(dbURL);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);

        /*  To connect database, you need to specify the database name, if the database 
            doesn't exist then MongoDB creates it automatically. */
        MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDb");
        System.out.println("Connected to database successfully");

        MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("myCollection");
        System.out.println("Collection created successfully");

        url = new URL(targetURL);
        urlConnection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =  new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
```

Comment: Please, post the xml as code, not as a picture.

Comment: `<SERVERPERFORMANCEMETRICS>
<SERVERNAME>abc</SERVERNAME>
<SERVERSTARTUPTIME>11/25/2016 11:00 AM</SERVERSTARTUPTIME>
<TOTALMASTERREQUESTS>4</TOTALMASTERREQUESTS>
<TOTALRENDERERREQUESTS>13</TOTALRENDERERREQUESTS>
<FAILEDREQUESTS>10</FAILEDREQUESTS>
</SERVERPERFORMANCEMETRICS>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself using **json-java jar**

```
       if (inputStream != null) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            //BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
            System.out.println(jsonObject);

            org.bson.Document jsonDocument = org.bson.Document.parse(jsonObject.toString());
            mongoCollection.insertOne(jsonDocument);
            System.out.println("Collection inserted successfully");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use W3C's `DocumentBuilder`:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
```